# How to map over a Pair/Tuple?

Tags: tuples, idris

In Haskell I would do `join (***)`. In Idris `flatten (***)` does not work (`(***)` is complicated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Idris, there's no `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` instances for `r -> _` and no `Arrow` instance for `->`, only via [`Morphism`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Morphisms.idr), so using `flatten` to do `\f x -> f x x` leads to horribly verbose code full of going from/to `Morphism`.

You *can* do it, of course, I'm just not sure it's worth it... compare this:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Morphisms

both : (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
both = applyMor . applyMor (flatten (Mor (Mor . (***)))) . Mor
```

to this:

```
both : (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
both f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```